# How to solve weight dominance counting problem?

Tags: algorithm

Weighted Dominance Counting Problem: given a set S of n weighted points, compute for each point p of S the sum of the weights of all points in S that dominate p.
Could this problem solved in O(n log^d(n)) time for a set S of d-dimensional points?

Comment: What do you think? What's your reasoning so far?

Comment: Please define "dominance". Is it when all corresponding coordinate are less or equal?

Comment: I have tried divide and conquer, but I didn't figure out how to merge the two parts in linear time. I also thought about the prefix sum, but it seems to be quadratic time.

Comment: p = (a, b) dominates q = (c, d) iff a <= c and b <= d

Comment: so if a <= c and b > d, it's a tie?